# Enforce NOT to pronounce sh in a word

Tags: pronunciation, translation, phonetics, transliteration

I have a word in the Arabic language that is transliterated into **Mushib** in English. It means **Verbose**. I need to enforce the pronunciation of this word to be Mus-Hib (Without pronouncing the sh sound)

Is there a way that's better than using a "-" (dash)?

Comment: What's wrong with *mus-hib*? I don't speak Arabic, but are there other Arabic words with similar pronunciations, and if so how have you seen them transliterated?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean مطول (mutul)? Mushib means companion or friend.

Comment: The only only way of presenting it so that there is no risk *sh*, but there is a clear *h*, is with a hyphen or the use of phonetic symbols. You simply can't spell it as a single unpunctuated word without the possibility of mispronunciation. Presenting it as two words would also work: *Muss Hib*. I'll also note that some people would *not* pronounce *Mus* and *Muss* the same way, which is why I used the latter. (*Mus* could be pronounced as *mooze*.)

Comment: @JasonBassford I was trying to find how to write its phonetic symbol when transitioning from s to h, can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Better asked on Linguistics, Yousef, as this is not an English word.

Answer (score 0):

Use the International Phonetic Alphabet: /mʌs'hiːb/